# Display own and friend posts, with php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli, foreach

I want to display my own posts (as default) but also display friend posts if `Status = '1'`

I only have this code which is showing all the posts with related images and content, because I don't know how to create that code that I am looking for.

### **The database structures**

> posts:

```
| commentid |  comment  | imagesid | author |
---------------------------------------------
|     1     |   fool    |   5557   | test   |
|     2     |  fool2    |   5585   | devel  |
---------------------------------------------
```

> multiple_image:

```
| id |  image  | imagesid | author |
------------------------------------
| 1  |  name1  |    5557  | test   |
| 2  |  name2  |    5557  | test   |
| 3  |  name3  |    5585  | devel  |
------------------------------------
```

> Connections:

```
| id |  Friend | FriendReferee | Status | 
-----------------------------------------
| 1  |  test   |     devel     |    1   |
-----------------------------------------
```

---

### **The current fetching structure**

> The actual code for fetching image(s):

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM multiple_image";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $imgs[$row['imagesid]][$row['id']]= "<img width='' src='../images/".$row['name']."' >"; // array of image id's, with arrays of images inside them.
  } 

 }
```

> Fetching the related texts

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $commentsToImages[$row['commentid']] = $row['imagesid'];
      $comments[$row['commentid']] = $row['comment']; 
  }     
 }
```

> Displaying the results in sperated divs

```
foreach($commentsToImages as $commentID =>$imagesID) {
    ?>
<div class='main'>
  <div class='comments'>


<?php echo $comments[$commentID];?>
  </div>
  <div class='pics'>
    <?php
          foreach($imgs[$imagesID] as $img) { 
                  echo $img;
          }
    ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

I tried to do it with JOIN and with if else statement, but not really working as I want it.

Comment: Is `iamgesid` on `posts` table a typo in the question or database?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone, yes it is and fixed it. :)

Comment: It's not clear enough to me what your table structure actually is intended to be. I would expect table *posts* like *(id, user_id, comment, image_id)* and *connections* like *(user_id, friend_id, ...)*, both refering the *user* table *(id, user_name, ...)*. Then you could build a JOIN on user ids.

Comment: It is the same as you described but with the author name instead of user_id or friend_id, also updated my question.

Comment: You should normalize the database based on ids instead of redundant names. There should be a master table holding the names. This is joined based on ids in queries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Can you please show an example for my question with user_id and friend_id?

Comment: You're speaking about friend connections and your intention to show other posts based on friend status, but your current code implies showing comments on posts rather than posts of friends. You need to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I only show the code that shows the comments with the images, because I don't know how to show the own and friends' posts with this code. I thought, someone can work with the code that I have currently and make the code that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a `user_id` on the tables `users`, `posts` and `connections`. Also the `friend_id` refers the `user_id` of the `users` table.

Then you `JOIN` the tables `posts` and `users` on `user_id`. The author is retrieved by a lookup for the user name by id.

```
SELECT
 `p`.`post_id`,
 `p`.`content`    `Post Content`,
 `u`.`user_name`  `Author`
FROM
  `posts`        `p`
INNER JOIN 
  `users`        `u`  USING(`user_id`)
WHERE 
  `p`.`user_id` = 1
;
```

Now you can `LEFT JOIN` the table `connections` where the post is from a friend you want to see posts from. You want to filter all `posts` which have a specific `user_id` or the joined `connection` table has the specific `friend_id`, e.g. `1`:

```
SELECT
 `p`.`post_id`,
 `p`.`content`    `Post Content`,
 `u`.`user_name`  `Author`
FROM
  `posts`        `p`
INNER JOIN 
  `users`        `u`  USING(`user_id`)
LEFT JOIN
  `connections`  `c`  ON(`c`.`show_posts`  AND  `p`.`user_id` = `c`.`friend_id`)
WHERE 
  1 in (`p`.`user_id`, `c`.`user_id`)
ORDER BY `p`.`post_id`
;
```

The database structure used for this example is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
  user_id    INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name  VARCHAR(20)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `connections`
(
  `user_id`    INT  NOT NULL,
  `friend_id`  INT  NOT NULL,
  `show_posts` BOOL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`, `friend_id`)
)
;

CREATE TABLE `posts`
(
  `post_id`   INT  NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
  `user_id`   INT  NOT NULL,
  `content`   TEXT(2000)
)
;

INSERT INTO `users`
  (`user_name`)
VALUES
  ('Tom'  ),
  ('Sarah'),
  ('Ben'  )
;

INSERT INTO `connections`
VALUES
  (1,2, true ), -- Tom/Sarah, Tom wants Sarah's posts
  (2,1, false), -- Sarah/Tom, Sarah does not want Tom's posts
  (1,3, false), -- Tom/Ben,   Tom does not want Ben's posts
  (3,1, true )  -- Ben/Tom,   Ben does not want Tom's posts
;

INSERT INTO `posts`
  (`user_id`, `content`)
VALUES
  (1, 'First post by Tom.'   ),
  (2, 'First post by Sarah.' ),
  (1, 'Second post by Tom.'  ),
  (3, 'First post by Ben.'   ),
  (3, 'Second post by Ben.'  ),
  (2, 'Second post by Sarah.'),
  (3, 'Third post by Ben.'   )
;
```

[Try online](https://paiza.io/projects/DUk0kJQay_zSN_X7p39T9w?language=mysql)

Comment: How can I display the friends' (if it is true)  and my own posts with the related images and content using this database scheme?

Comment: So I have to update my database scheme and the query?

Comment: You can alter your tables to get a similar scheme as demonstrated.

Comment: Alright. One more thing. Do I still have to use that array loop method that I have currently to seprate the texts and the images in a different div in your method or not?

Comment: You can have a main loop for all posts, the own and friend's ones. If there is only one image associated with the post, you can join it as well. Otherwise you can perform an inner loop.

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @Chris_00 You can check the provided "Try online" link, Tom is the user 1 and Sarah his friend of which he wants to see posts. Both, Tom's and Sarah's posts are actually selected.

Comment: I already checked the online version that you have provided and created a database and php project from it and it worked. I meant example for the related images (inner loop) and contents.

Comment: @Chris_00 In order to the StackOverflow policy, questions and answers shall focus only one specific issue or they will be closed as "too broad". When an answer works as originally asked in the question, it should be checked as the *accepted answer*. You are welcome to open a new question asking for further details of your project.